# Define a state using array map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, react-hooks

I want to use map method with an array to define initial value of a state.

My thoughts:

```
import data from "./data.js"

const [state, setState] = useState([

    data.map((item)=>
        {
            value: item.value
        }
    )

])
```

But it's not working. Is there a good practice about this case?

Comment: What's not working about it? do you get any errors?

Comment: You're trying to define an array within an array.  Was that your intent?  What specifically is "not working"?

Comment: You have a syntax issue. Assuming you meant to return an array of objects, put parens around the curly braces. `({ ... })` otherwise the curly braces are being seen as a block, not an object literal.

Comment: What does the data.js data look like?

Comment: That was the answer that I was looking for. Thanks man! @evolutionxbox